# Javascript Multiple Switches

Tags: javascript

Sorry total noob here. I just need to add a pricing calculator on my website with the following price list and conditions.

## x y   z   cost#

X1  Y1  6Z  $30.00
X1  Y1  12Z $25.00
X1  Y1  24Z $22.00
X1  Y1  2Z  $20.00
X1  Y1  7Z  $14.00
X1  Y1  14Z $10.00
            
X1  Y2  6Z  $35.00
X1  Y2  12Z $30.00
X1  Y2  24Z $27.00

How can I make a script for this? Here's my initial code based on a tutorial I watched, but it's not working.

```
var tmp_total=0;
//get x
var x=fld_uiiwz0j734a_value_char;
console.log('x : '+x);
//get y
var y=fld_uiw41b5djqw_value_char;
console.log('y : '+y);
//get z
var z=fld_uipdg8cnw12_value_char;
console.log('z : '+z);
//get cost
var cost=fld_uie6n1eqh3f_value;
console.log('cost : '+cost);

var cost=0;

switch(String(x)){
  case 'X1';
    switch(String(y)){
        case 'Y1';
            switch(String(z)){
                case '6Z';
                    cost=30;
                case '12Z';
                    cost=25;
    break;
}

tmp_total=(cost*z);

return tmp_total;
```

Comment: What exactly is `fld_uiiwz0j734a_value_char`? Or `fld_uiw41b5djqw_value_char`, etc? You never define those variables. (Consider using more sensible variable names)

Comment: It's better to use shorter variable names, such as `字的`.

Answer (score 1):

simply do :

```
switch( `${x} ${y} ${z}`) {
  case 'X1 Y1 6Z':  cost = 30; break;
  case 'X1 Y1 12Z': cost = 25; break;
  case 'X1 Y1 24Z': cost = 22; break;
  case 'X1 Y1 2Z':  cost = 20; break;
  case 'X1 Y1 7Z':  cost = 14; break;
  case 'X1 Y1 14Z': cost = 10; break;
  case 'X1 Y2 6Z':  cost = 35; break;
  case 'X1 Y2 12Z': cost = 30; break;
  case 'X1 Y2 24Z': cost = 27; break;
}
```